# Cross platform AES/CBC encryption decryption between openssl C and android

Tags: android, c, android-studio, encryption

I just want AES/CBC 128 bit encryption decryption in openSSl c and Android with identical result.
I have to send encrypted data using pre defined 16 bytes key from android to c via bluetooth.
So is there any common mechanism which i can use in both to produce identical result of encryption and decryption.
Any help would be appreciate.
Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

I found a solution which work perfectly for Android.
I am going to post the answer if it would help anyone.

```
static String IV = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";

static String encryptionKey = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    public static String decrypt(byte[] cipherText, String encryptionKey) throws Exception{
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/ZeroBytePadding"/*, "SunJCE"*/);
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key,new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(cipherText),"UTF-8");
    }
    public static byte[] encrypt(String plainText, String encryptionKey) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/ZeroBytePadding"/*, "SunJCE"*/);
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key,new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        return cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }
//To Encrypt

byte[] cipher = encrypt(plaintext, encryptionKey);

System.out.print("cipher: ");

//To Decrypt

String decrypted = decrypt(cipher, encryptionKey);

System.out.println("decrypt: " + decrypted);
```

Comment: Why bother doing AES-encryption at all if you're going to use a hardcoded key and iv?

Comment: Down-voted because of insecure key derivation (`encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8")`)

Comment: it was just for an example . we can change it and will work dynamically not insecure and hardcoded.